# Define a backup job on daily basis

Tags: 2013, site-collection, administration, timer-jobs, backup

I usually run the following three statements manually inside SharePoint power shell :-

```
Backup-spsite -identity http://tgvsps01   -path T:\back\Team.bak –force
Backup-spsite -identity http://tgvsps01/discussionforum/generalDiscussion  -path T:\back\Discussion.bak –force
Backup-spsite -identity http://tgvsps01/core/CustomerServiceKB -path T:\back\Wiki.bak –force
```

To backup three site collections and store the generated three back files, inside a shared drive

But my question is there a way to force these statement to run daily for example at 5 am, or twice a day at 12 am & 12 pm  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

- Configuring a SQL job to backup the content databases - as opposed to SharePoint's backup commandlets

or

- Use a Windows Scheduled Task to run your Powershell commands
  For the scheduled task I usually have two files:

  1. backup.bat - with the commandline below, that executes the second file

     ```
     "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-NoExit %~dp0\backup.ps1'"
     ```
  2. backup.ps1 - that has the powershell commands that will be executed

     ```
     Backup-spsite -identity http://<tgvsps01>   -path T:\back\Team.bak –force
     Backup-spsite -identity http://<tgvsps01>/discussionforum/generalDiscussion  -path T:\back\Discussion.bak –force
     Backup-spsite -identity http://<tgvsps01>/core/CustomerServiceKB -path T:\back\Wiki.bak –force
     ```

I then create the scheduled task to run "Backup.bat" instead of the powershell

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266384(v=office.15).aspx

Keep in mind that the Backup-SPSite command is ideal to be used only to backup less then 15gb of data.

Comment: i think that the problem is that the sp1 will open using windows poer shell and not sharepoint power shell (i know that they are almost the same). because if i open the b.sp1 file direclty , it will open using windows poershell, and if i run it i will get these exceptions:- "ckup-spsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." Which means that windows poer shell can not recongnize Backup-spsite !!

Comment: Try adding "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" to the beginning of your script. It should recognize the commands after that.

Comment: ok thanks i added this , but now if i manually run the ps1 script it will create the three backup files. but if i schedule this using Task scheduler then no backup files are being generated,, can u advice ?

Comment: Did you set a user to which the task will run under? Does that user meet the requirements for the procedure?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: yes i set my username, and i am able to run this script manully

Comment: Just tested and worked fine. Had to set the task to "run with highest privileges", "Run whether the user is logged on or not" and I used a .bat file to launch the Powershell, used the following command line: "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-NoExit %~dp0\backup.ps1'"

Comment: yes i already set these settings inside the task scheduler "run with highest privileges" + "Run whether the user is logged on or not". but i am not sure where exactly i should write this "-Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-NoExit %~dp0\backup.ps1'""

Comment: I have two files: a backup.bat with the command line "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-NoExit %~dp0\backup.ps1'" and a backup.ps1 which has the powershell script that will be executed. Both in the same folder.

Comment: ok in my case i have a ps1 which i am trying to run using Task Schduler, i can not understand your point ,, why i need two scripts to run..

Comment: Using only the Powershell I was able to get it working by setting the action's path as and the argument box %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe as -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "C:\TEMP\bkp\Deploy.ps1"

Comment: ok thanks i will try your approach , but i have one question where i should located the backup.ps1? i mean what does  "%~dp0\backup.ps1" refer to ?

Comment: it refers to the folder of the running batch file

Answer (score 1):

Create standard windows scheduler task and run batch file with your PowerShell commands:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script

Comment: thanks for the reply. ok i save my three statments inside a ps1 file , then i follow these steps http://sharepointdrive.blogspot.com/2012/04/automating-sharepoint-site-backup-using_14.html but i will not get any files generated...

Comment: Create .bat file with code to run powershell scritp: 'powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "& PathToYourBackupScript.ps1'. In program/script field of task put your .bat file.

Comment: i specify PowerShell.exe in the program.script that will call a sp1 file not bat file ?? can u adivce ?

Comment: Just put parameters to add argument field:-executionpolicy unrestricted -command "& C:\TEMP\PowerShellTest\test.ps1

Comment: ok i add the following argument -executionpolicy unrestricted -command &'c:\b.ps1' ,, but will not solve the problem

Comment: Add Sharepoint snapin to powershell session. In ps1 add to top: Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: i can not understand your point, can u explain it more please

Comment: now i try running the b.sp1 file directly but seems that i will get the following exception "Backup-spsite : The term 'Backup-spsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.""

Comment: Sharepoint Powershell console uses "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" snap-in. In prev comment i have recommended add this snap-in to your powershell session.

Comment: now becuase ifi run the b.sp1 using windows power shell i will get error, but if i run it using sharepoint power shell it will work,,, so i am assuming that the Task Schduler will try running the script using windows poer shell, and this is why it will not work.. so i should add " Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" to b.sp1 file?

Comment: ok now i added "Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" to the b.sp1 file. and if i run the sp1 file manually the backup will work, but using Task Scheduler it iwll not work ... altouhgh i specify in the action section to run a program using windows power shell..